# YouTube thumbnail link doesn't work in all cases

Tags: youtube

An application I'm working on needs to get HQ YouTube thumbnails given a URL. [Using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/823435), I tried using the `maxresdefault.jpg` to get the maximum resolution of the thumbnail but on some videos (seemingly random), the request 404's.

Here are some examples:

- http://img.youtube.com/vi/zIez5QVE3NI/maxresdefault.jpg works
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/DaAfe5xTm8w/maxresdefault.jpg doesn't work

Using the same URL's, other requests using the same video keys do work:

- http://img.youtube.com/vi/zIez5QVE3NI/default.jpg works
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/DaAfe5xTm8w/default.jpg works

Why doesn't `maxresdefault.jpg` reliably return the image? Both of those videos are public and can be embedded.

I'd use `0.jpg` but it has black bars on the top and bottom of the image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I understand it, YouTube only generates high-res stills for high-res videos.  The first one you link was uploaded at a resolution of at least 1080p, while the second was less than 720p.

Looks like the only thing you can do is pull the video feed, check that to see if a high-res still has been generated and up-scale the smaller one yourself if not.

All¹ YouTube stills are presented in the 4:3 aspect ratio, so will always have black bars at the top and bottom if the video is 16:9.  In HTML/CSS, this is easily combated by setting the image as the background of a div and sizing the div to the correct aspect.

¹ Except the mqdefault.jpg stills, which are all in 16:9 aspect (320x180)

Comment: It looks like some of the "mqdefault.jpg" thumbnails do not have the black bars top and bottom.

Comment: I'm don't think any of the mqdefault thumbs have black bars. They're all 16:9, if I remember correctly. Should note that in the answer, really.

Answer (score 8):

Update 2015 : 
None of your 'maxresdefault' link seems to be working

Try these:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

Comment: How to get them in high res?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2019** ::

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

Seems to return highest possible image....

1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg return previews through the length of the clip which are handy also ;)