# Url of large image of a YouTube video

Tags: image, url, youtube, thumbnails, image-size

I'm interested in getting a preview image of a youtube video for my application
I'm using the url to the previews:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/EqWRZrupLrI/0.jpg

but this has little two black rows, up and down, and I wish it were bigger.
I have read that the 0 is the bigger picture.

anyone know if it is possible to obtain a url with a better image?, for my project, I need the image is on a url

I appreciate the help

Regards :)

Answer (score 22):

`0.jpg` is the full-size 480p thumbnail and there is no bigger thumbnail except for full HD videos (`maxresdefault.jpg`).

But why do you expect a bigger thumbnail for such a video ? Your video example has a resolution of 240p, the thumbnail is already much bigger than the video resolution.

Answer (score 9):

Each of every image has 4 category like

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

Also you can get more image size by this

-- For default

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

-- For high quality

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

-- For medium quality

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

-- For max size

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following SO post:

[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

[YouTube thumbnail link doesn't work in all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334710/youtube-thumbnail-link-doesnt-work-in-all-cases)

It will surely solve your problem. I recommend to query the youtube api to get the thumbnail with max resolution.

Comment: This **is** the YouTube API for getting video thumbnail or at least it is the only documented way in the Google YouTube API v2.

Comment: I don't get what are you suggesting in this comment. For this particular video, 0.jpg is the max thumbnail. But it can change on high res video.

Comment: To explain my first comment, you recommended the OP to query the youtube API in order to get the thumbnail max resolution but I was just pointing out that it was precisely what he was doing, unless you know of any other API to get the video thumbnail.

Comment: He never mentioned that he is using API. He is using the thumbnail in the format of http://img.youtube.com/vi/<videoid>/0.jpg. However, a video may have bigger image than that. So, relying on youtube data api is the best way.