# Displayed image returned as 404

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-404

get posts from an API and sometimes the image those posts contain is like this:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e5wXRrQfooc/default.jpg

But when I put it in a

```
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e5wXRrQfooc/default.jpg" />
```

It displayed a missing image icon:

http://jsfiddle.net/x8hmxovc/

It seems thats their return 404 image, but how do I get it when all I have is the url?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the youtube API to show the video thumbnails
There are a lot of posts already dealing with this i think

Like these ones:
[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

[Url of large image of a YouTube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222407/url-of-large-image-of-a-youtube-video)

[YouTube thumbnail link doesn't work in all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334710/youtube-thumbnail-link-doesnt-work-in-all-cases)

Comment: Thanks.
Yes indeed i'm using youtube api and I am aware the user doesn't exist anymore / video was removed - how can I know it though by having the url only?
I have a fallback-src url for those cases, but those links don't fallback but instead return me an image, but I can't display it

Answer (score 0):

By the way the Youtube Account which this thumbnail contained doesnt exist anymore I think

If this is the link to the Video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5wXRrQfooc