# Wanted to get the full size thumbnails from a youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know that one can get the YouTube video thumbnails by:
https://img.youtube.com/vi/*video_link*/maxresdefault.jpg

But the problem is some of the videos don't show a full sized image, rather, it shows up an empty box, like this:
[image: This link shows up an empty box]

Here is the link of the video that I'm trying to get [the video link](https://img.youtube.com/vi/faFRo3xSsaA/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: You can get a full breakdown of each image size available, their associated link, and which are guaranteed to be available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20542029/8285811).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api). It stated that each YouTube video has 4 generated images. The first one in the list is a full size image and others are thumbnail images.

> The default thumbnail image (ie. one of `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`) is:
>
> ```
> https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
> ```
>
> For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to
>   this:
>
> ```
> https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
> ```
>
> There is also a medium quality version of the thumbnail, using a url
>   similar to the HQ:
>
> ```
> https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
> ```
>
> For the standard definition version of the thumbnail, use a url
>   similar to this:
>
> ```
> https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
> ```
>
> For the maximum resolution version of the thumbnail use a url similar
>   to this:
>
> ```
> https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
> ```
>
> All of the above urls are available over http too. Additionally, the
>   slightly shorter hostname `i3.ytimg.com` works in place of
>   `img.youtube.com` in the example urls above.

Also based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334710/youtube-thumbnail-link-doesnt-work-in-all-cases), be noted that YouTube only generates high-res stills for high-res videos. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this solves the issue. I'm going to use the standard version. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also access specific frames with `hq + number`, e.g. https://img.youtube.com/vi/g2PvDkbZDtk/hq1.jpg